# Make existing web application responsive

Tags: css, responsive

I have an angularJS/Jquery based web-application. In shortage of time many pages have inline styles. There is a common CSS file which is included on every page. The problem is that : on resize of browser or on projector my application looks distorted. All the pages of application not having unform layout, few are list pages, few are form pages and few others are widget with graphs. Could anybody help me to make this web-application responsive without making much changes.

I need a quick-start tip/third party tool or a guidance document to optimize CSS and make the weUI responsive.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is a framework that implements responsive layouts.

Popular frameworks are Bootstrap and Materialize. Those are a good place to start. Learn about their grid layout, which will help you set how each container element will be viewed on different displays.

http://getbootstrap.com/

http://materializecss.com/ (for Google's material design approach).

There is a lot to talk about when designing web apps for mobile and desktops, but these frameworks are a good start.

Making web apps responsive is not a quick-and-dirty job, and maintenance is a constant work. It sounds like you have a lot of work ahead of you. Definitely with making many changes...

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a try. However I don't want to re-write existing code. Looking for a solution which works well with minimum changes.

Comment: I am afraid you are going to hit your head in the wall. If you wish to fix a brokenly designed website, with minimum code-write - get someone to write the code for you :-) Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Can you just use CSS?

See this, if you haven't:
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp